# How to create horizontal line with little transparent ends

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to create this green line?

[image]
I tried to create this `div` but endings are too sharp

```
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
background: linear-gradient(#01f4e4, #01f4e4, transparent);
border-radius: 50%;
```

I am using image on website, but i am curious, if it can be done with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a 3 way gradient like this. Check out [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for an easy way to create them.

```css
body {
    background:black;
    padding-top:100px;
}
div {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:3px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(34,183,67,0.98) 50%, rgba(38,184,70,1) 51%, rgba(225,228,226,0) 99%, rgba(229,229,229,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(34,183,67,0.98) 50%,rgba(38,184,70,1) 51%,rgba(225,228,226,0) 99%,rgba(229,229,229,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(34,183,67,0.98) 50%,rgba(38,184,70,1) 51%,rgba(225,228,226,0) 99%,rgba(229,229,229,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
hr.style-two {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0));
}
hr {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
    -webkit-margin-start: auto;
    -webkit-margin-end: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 50px 0 5px 0;
 }
```

```html
<hr class="style-two">
```

you can get more idea from

here http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

Answer (score 1):

Use full rgba colors and define the points where the gradient occurs

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 254, 228, 0) 0%, rgba(1, 254, 228, 1) 20%, rgba(1, 254, 228, 1) 80%, rgba(1, 254, 228, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```